# Easier xskakloop or xskak-only solution for a chessgame-loop

Tags: chessboard, xskak

[image]

I created a loop for a chess game. 
I used a tikz-foreach method and created a (code-intensive) `\MoveIdList` for it

*The question is: can the optics be implemented with an xskak-only solution with a \xskakloop loop?* 
I couldn't do that; because in that case I don't know how to set the highlighting style.

Note: I would like to keep the (small) tcolorbox-itemize part as shown.

```
%\documentclass[margin=5mm, varwidth]{standalone}
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=7mm, paperwidth=200mm, paperheight=120mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}


\colorlet{mycol}{orange}
\colorlet{altcol}{mycol!22}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{}}

% xskak.sty  ============================
\makeatletter
\xskaknewstyleitem[% copy from styleC
 opencommands={\begin{tabular}{L{2em} L{3em} L{3em}}},
 closecommands={\end{tabular}},
 blackopen=\ldots,
 beforenumber={%  \cellcolor{brown}  
\ifnum\xskak@val@movenr=\MoveNo \cellcolor{mycol}\fi%
},
beforewhite={&% 
\ifnum\xskak@val@movenr=\MoveNo %
   \ifnum\IsWhitePlayer=1 \cellcolor{mycol} \else \cellcolor{altcol}\fi 
\fi},
afterwhite={  },
beforeblack={&
\ifnum\xskak@val@movenr=\MoveNo %
   \ifnum\IsWhitePlayer=0 \cellcolor{mycol} \else \cellcolor{altcol} \fi 
\fi},
 afterblack={ \\[0.125em]  },
 whiteopen={.\,},% copy from style UF
]{TabularStyle}
\makeatother
\xskaknewstyle[
styleitem=TabularStyle, 
font=\bfseries,% optional
]{styleCx}
% ====================================

\begin{document}

\newchessgame[id=MyGame] 
%\hidemoves{1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3  a6 6. Be3 e6 7. g4 e5 8. Nf5 g6 9. g5}
\hidemoves{1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 
3. Nc3 dxe4 4. Nxe4 Nd7 5. Ng5 Ngf6 
6. Bd3 e6 7. N1f3 h6 8. Nxe6 Qe7 9. O-O fxe6 10. Bg6+ Kd8 
11. Bf4 b5 12. a4 Bb7 13. Re1 Nd5 14. Bg3 Kc8 15. axb5 cxb5 
16. Qd3 Bc6 17. Bf5 exf5 18. Rxe7 Bxe7 19. c4
}
%\printchessgame[id=MyGame, style=styleCx]

% Create MoveIdList ========================
%Test: lastplayer: \xskakgetgame{lastplayer}, lastmovenr: \xskakgetgame{lastmovenr}

\newcommand{\pMoveIdList}{}% Name reservieren
\let\pMoveIdList=\empty% Liste erstellen

\def\LastMoveNr{\xskakgetgame{lastmovenr}}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\PreLastMoveNr{\LastMoveNr-1}

\foreach \MoveNo  in {1,...,\PreLastMoveNr}{%%
\foreach \Player in {w,b}{%
  \ifx\empty\pMoveIdList{} \xdef\pMoveIdList{\MoveNo\Player}%
  \else% 
\xdef\pMoveIdList{\pMoveIdList, \MoveNo\Player}%
\fi
}%
}%%

\def\BlackPlayerId{b}
%\def\WhitePlayerId{w}
\xdef\LastPlayerId{\xskakgetgame{lastplayer}}
\ifx\LastPlayerId\BlackPlayerId% 
\xdef\MoveIdList{\pMoveIdList, \xskakgetgame{lastmovenr}w, \xskakgetgame{lastmovenr}b}%
\else% 
\xdef\MoveIdList{\pMoveIdList, \xskakgetgame{lastmovenr}w}%
\fi%
%TEST:  LastPlayerId: \LastPlayerId, BlackPlayerId: \BlackPlayerId, MoveIdList: \MoveIdList
% =======================================


\foreach[count=\No] \MoveId in \MoveIdList{%%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\MoveNo{ceil(\No/2)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\IsWhitePlayer{mod(\No,2)}%
\begin{tcbitemize}[sharp corners, raster equal height=rows,
raster column skip=0mm,
boxrule=1.2pt, boxsep=1mm, 
colback=white, colbacktitle=lightgray,  coltitle=black, fonttitle=\bfseries,
toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm,
raster every box/.style={toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm,},
]
\tcbitem[adjusted title={Move \MoveId}] \chessboard[
moveid=\MoveId, setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}] 
\tcbitem[adjusted title={Tot. No: \No, IsWhitePlayer: \IsWhitePlayer}
] \printchessgame[style=styleCx]
\end{tcbitemize}
\newpage
}%%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I was able to create it with a xskak-loop. But for the annotations `\printchessgame[style=styleCx]` I needed numbered saveboxes from `\usepackage{xsavebox}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=7mm, paperwidth=200mm, paperheight=120mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xsavebox}% <--- !

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false}

% Creating a tabular style  =========================
\colorlet{mycol}{yellow}
\colorlet{altcol}{mycol!22}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}<{}}

\makeatletter
\xskaknewstyleitem[% copy from styleC
 opencommands={\begin{tabular}{l L{2.5em} L{2.5em}}},
 closecommands={\end{tabular}},
 blackopen=\ldots,
 beforenumber={%  \cellcolor{brown}  
\ifnum\xskak@val@movenr=\MoveNo \cellcolor{mycol}\fi%
},
beforewhite={&% 
\ifnum\xskak@val@movenr=\MoveNo %
   \ifnum\IsWhitePlayer=1 \cellcolor{mycol} \else \cellcolor{altcol}\fi 
\fi},
afterwhite={  },
beforeblack={&
\ifnum\xskak@val@movenr=\MoveNo %
   \ifnum\IsWhitePlayer=0 \cellcolor{mycol} \else \cellcolor{altcol} \fi 
\fi},
 afterblack={ \\[0.125em]  },
 whiteopen={.\,},% copy from style UF
]{TabularStyle}
\makeatother
\xskaknewstyle[
styleitem=TabularStyle, 
font=\bfseries,% optional
]{styleCx}
% =====================================
    
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\hidemoves{1. e4 c6 2. d4 d5 
3. Nc3 dxe4 4. Nxe4 Nd7 5. Ng5 Ngf6 
6. Bd3 e6 7. N1f3 h6 8. Nxe6 Qe7 9. O-O fxe6 10. Bg6+ Kd8 
11. Bf4 b5 12. a4 Bb7 13. Re1 Nd5 14. Bg3 Kc8 15. axb5 cxb5 
16. Qd3 Bc6 17. Bf5 exf5 18. Rxe7 Bxe7 19. c4#
}

\foreach[count=\No] \MoveNo in {1,...,\xskakgetgame{lastmovenr}}{
% White Player =================
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\IsWhitePlayer{1}
\def\PlayerId{w}
\def\boxname{mybox-\MoveNo\PlayerId}
\xsbox{\boxname}{\printchessgame[style=styleCx]}
%Test: No: \No, MoveNo: \MoveNo, IsWhitePlayer: \IsWhitePlayer, boxname: \boxname \\  \xusebox{\boxname} \\
% Black Player =================
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\IsWhitePlayer{0}
\def\PlayerId{b}
\def\boxname{mybox-\MoveNo\PlayerId}
\xsbox{\boxname}{\printchessgame[style=styleCx]}
%Test: No: \No, MoveNo: \MoveNo, IsWhitePlayer: \IsWhitePlayer, boxname: \boxname \\  \xusebox{\boxname} \\
}
% Test:  \xusebox{mybox-1w}, \xusebox{mybox-2b}  

\tcbset{myrasterstyle/.style={
sharp corners, raster equal height=rows,
raster column skip=0mm,
boxrule=1.2pt, boxsep=1mm, 
colback=white, colbacktitle=lightgray,  coltitle=black, fonttitle=\bfseries,
toptitle=1mm, bottomtitle=1mm,
},}

\xskakloop[step=1]{%%
\begin{tcbitemize}[myrasterstyle]
\tcbitem[adjusted title={Move \xskakget{movenr}\xskakget{player}}
] \chessboard[setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}] 
\tcbitem[]  \xusebox{mybox-\xskakget{movenr}\xskakget{player}}
\end{tcbitemize}
\newpage}%%
\end{document}
```